# Know if my script runs from a webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a third party JS that is being loaded from many sites. For my statistics - I wish to know if the site is loaded from an Android WebView. I tried to find a difference between the user-agents but couldn't.

Is there a user-agent difference? Is there a JS command that would result differently in a WebView?

Thanks,
Roni

Comment: Why is that important to you? (I don't really care about the answer, but you should ask yourself this question). It seems to me like it shouldn't matter and perhaps that you're better off not knowing.

Comment: I use cookie syncing between different domains. Web views do not store cookies between apps / sessions so I need to know determine weather its a new user or a webview.

Comment: So it's about tracking, not statistics? That's a big difference. To play advocate of the devil here: have you looked into other tracking methods like E-Tags?

Comment: I don't wish to track individuals, but to determine whether the user is "new" or "has no cookies because its a webview", so E-Tag tracking will be over-complex and won't help diffrentiate clients behind proxies